# Button Shown as pressed on start of Activity in Android

Tags: java, android

How can i show a button as it is pressed whenever the activity is created and UI is shown to user in Android?

Comment: Can you describe it more please? Do you need any callback on that "pressed"? Just appearance? Is the button after that still clickable? Do you need a toggle-button functionality? (stay pressed / released)

Comment: just appearance of being pressed. Still clickable, no toggle button isnt needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be okay:

```
@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.test_button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Clicked");
        }
    });
    // This will NOT trigger the onClickListener!
    button.setPressed(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the button selector state like the following code i.e(res/drawable/button.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/button_add_to_favorites_active">

</item>

<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_add_to_favorites_active">

</item>

<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_add_to_favorites_active">  //Here set the drawable looks like pressed one.      

</item>
</selector>
```